# Contact is not getting created from Pre-Chat form

Tags: case, error, contact, chat, pre-chat

I am having a problem with my pre-chat questions not creating a Contact if no match is found for the Contact. The Chat starts fine and the Case is created, but the Contact is not created and the Case does not update to the correct Record Type or any other pre-filled information I added on the Global Action. The owner of the Case remains as Automated Process

If a Contact is found, the Case is created with the correct record type and prefilled information. The owner is changed to the user accepting the Chat. I can see in the history that the Owner is changed and the data is updated appropriately.

I've checked validation rules, sharing rules, fls, and deactivated every process that runs on a Case and a Contact. I've created a Contact manually without an Account and created a Case with that same Contact with no issues. I checked the debug logs on Automated User and did not see any errors. I've tested this in other orgs and it works as expected.

Something is telling me that the User called Automated Process is the cause of this, but there is no profile associated with that User so I can't check permissions.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue to determine why a Contact is not being created and the Case is not being updated properly?

Comment: can you post your pre chat JS?

Comment: It is not JS. It is the standard out of the box Embedded Service chat which uses quick actions to create records.

Comment: @ScottSearle You ever figure this out? Having the same issue myself now.